# Finding all homographies preserving the upper right quarter of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

i am trying to solve the following problem:

find all homographies given by a two by two matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ which transform the upper right quarter $ \{ \Re z, \Im z > 0 \} $ onto itself.

All I have come up with that somehow it could be relevant that homographies of this set form a subgroup of homography group, so we can always consider an inverse transformation. Also considering image, pre-image of zero could be useful.

I think answer is compositions of scaling by nonenegative $a$ and symmetry of line y=x